# React renders before API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I make an API call to server to get the currentUser,

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadUser()
},[])
```

Since behaviour of React is like `render first run lifecycle methods second`, at first, my selector for user returns null which what I expect.

However I still got `user is null` error, so this is my code =>

```
const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated)
const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user)

const authLinks = (
    <nav className="auth-navbar">
        <div className="auth-navbar__dropdown">
            <button type="button" className="dropdown-btn" onClick={dropdown}><img src={profilephoto}></img></button>
            <div className="dropdown-menu">
                <Link to={`u/${user.username}`} className="dropdown-link">Profile</Link>
                <Link to="/settings" className="dropdown-link">Settings</Link>
                <Link to="/" onClick={onClickHandler} className="dropdown-link">Logout</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
if (user) {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <Link to="/" className="logo" >
                <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
            </Link>
            {isAuthenticated ? authLinks : guestLinks}
        </header>
    )
} else {
    return <p>loading..</p>
}
```

Questions like this have been asked before on stackoverflow but solutions are similar to mine and it still doesn't work. Please help me.

P.S: the default of `user` is `null` in the reducer.

EDIT: The action creator to load user =>

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch) => {

    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING })

    const config = {
        withCredentials: true
    }

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/user/', config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED,
                payload: res.data
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            dispatch({
                type: AUTH_ERROR
            })
        })
}
```

Normally user loads without error =>

[image: user]

reducer =>

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null,
}
export default function(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case USER_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case USER_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isLoading: false,
                user: action.payload
            }
```

Comment: Pls share the complete relevant code. Either the useEffect doesn't get triggered, or you introduced stale state or the API call is not correct. But we can't determine that without a bit more context.

Comment: What line specifically is the error being thrown on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make `authLinks` a function which executes and returns the relevant JSX only when `user` exists. As it is, the variable will try to access the property `user.username` before it has been initialised.

```
const authLinks = () => (
  ...
);
```

And then call it in the return.

```
{isAuthenticated ? authLinks() : guestLinks}
```